# Log version.jsp calls in seperate logfile with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat7

Our loadbalancer calls version.jsp every other second to check if the application is still alive. Problem is, our access.log files now get flooded with said version.jsp calls. Is there any sane way to log all version.jsp calls to a seperate logfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can play with the [Access Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes) and the two attributes it allows for matching a specific request (`conditionIf` , `conditionUnless`). This means you need two valves, each one will log in its file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Attribute conditionUnless in Tomcat server.xml

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b" conditionUnless="keepAlive" />

Now you can implement a filter for everything you don't want in access logfile. In the filter only add the parameter keepAlive to the request object, so the tomcat only logs requests that do not have the keepAlive parameter.